# Why would anyone like to host WCF using Tcp protocol instead of using a basic Http protocol?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, tcp

I am new to WCF and I learned that using WCF you can communicate between two or more distributed systems over various protocols and message formats. So far for practice purposes I have used basicHttpBinding. But for demonstration purposes I want to be really convinced where to use netTcpBinding or etc. Please tell me the scenario where net.TcpBinding becomes really useful and almost a must to opt for. 
Also as far as I know it is one of the major advantages that WCF offers over it's traditional various counterparts such as ASP .Net Web Services that it can seamlessly communicate over various protocols which other traditional Web Services can't. 
Is it true ? Please clarify.

Comment: The main reason to use NetTcpBinding is performance. Less overhead when compared to HTTP protocol + binary serialization. The drawback is interoperability.

Answer (score 3):

every binding for different goals
[image: bindins]

Comment: Thanks a ton. But can't I make a cross platform or rather cross - machine communication over Http Binding (Although I know that Tcp is connection oriented where Http is not) ? 
What problems would I face if I try to attempt Http instead of Tcp in such scenarios ?
Please I just want to make my doubts clear.

Comment: @user3655102 you can not receive data by other platform through tcp without black magic or custom binding

Answer (score 1):

Performance is much better with a binary protocol. Serialization is faster and the network is used less.

Also, the NetTcp binding supports more of .NET, for example generics. It is based on `BinaryFormatter`.

Also see burning_LEGION's diagram, I'm not going to copy it over.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some difference which will help you to understand the answer

**BasicHttpBinding** - main feature: uses *WS-I Basic Profile 1.1* standart mainly used for consuming the old ASMX WebServices. Other important features, you must pay attention on:

Works over http protocol
Supports security according to BasicHttpSecurityElement (None/Transport/Message/TransportWithMessageCredential/TransportCredentialOnly)
Supports message encoding with Mtom (Message Transmission Organization Mechanism 1.0 (MTOM) encoder), used for tranfer of messages with large binary attachments

**NetTcpBinding** - main feature: uses WS-* standart (has more features then WS-I Basic Profile 1.1) for deploying and consuming of the .NET WCF services in cross-machine communication environment. Other important features:

Works over tcp protocol
Supports security according to NetTcpSecurityElement (None/Transport/Message/Both)
Supports transactions
Supports reliable sessions (can support exactly-once delivery assurances)

[Choosing a Transport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769.aspx) This link is worth looking at

Comment: Thanks a ton. But can't I make a cross platform or rather cross - machine communication over Http Binding (Although I know that Tcp is connection oriented where Http is not) ? 
What problems would I face if I try to attempt Http instead of Tcp in such scenarios ?
Please I just want to make my doubts clear.